# find the object index using id in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json that contains many objects:

```
[Object, Object, Object, ... ]
```

Inside each object there is an object number and an id:

```
0: Object
id: "theObjectImLookingFor"
...
```

How can I find the object number (0) using the id "theObjectImLookingFor" in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function someFunc(){
    var objArr = [Object, Object, Object, ... ];
    for(var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++){
         if(objArr[i].id == "theObjectImLookingFor")
            return i;
    }
    return "No value matched";
}
```

Comment: He said the object number is a property name in the object, it's not necessarily the same as its index in the array.

Comment: yes, the object number is the object index, sorry if I was not clear

Answer (score 1):

This assumes there's only one property with a numeric name. This is a very strange way to store something you want to be able to look up. Why not give each object an `obj_number` property?

```
function find_object(json, str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if (json[i].id == str) {
            for (var key in json[i]) {
                if (IsNumeric(key)) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // Not found
}
```